# Perl: What is the definition of a test?

Tags: perl, testing

I feel a bit ashamed to ask this question but I am curious. I recently wrote a script (without organizing the code in modules) that reads log files of a store and saves the info to the data base.

For example, I  wrote something like this (via Richard Huxton):

```
while (<$infile>) {
    if (/item_id:(\d+)\s*,\s*sold/) {
        my $item_id = $1;
        $item_id_sold_times{$item_id}++;
    }
}
my @matched_items_ids = keys %item_id_sold_times;
my $owner_ids =
  Store::Model::Map::ItemOwnerMap->fetch_by_keys( \@matched_item_ids )
  ->entry();
for my $owner_id (@$owner_ids) {
    $item_id_owner_map{$owner_id}++;
}
```

Say, this script is called script.pl. When testing the file, I made a file script.t and had to repeat some blocks of script.pl in script.t. After copy pasting relevant code sections, I do confirmations like:

```
is( $item_id_sold_times{1}, 1, "Number of sold items of item 1" );
is( $item_id_owner_map{3},  8, "Number of sold items for owner 3" );
```

And so on and so on.

But some have pointed out that what I wrote is not a test. It is a confirmation script. A good test would involve writing the code with modules, writing a script that kicks the methods in the modules and write a test for the module.

This has made me think about what is the definition of a test most widely used in software engineering. Perhaps some of you that have even tested Perl core functions can give me a hand. A script (not modulized) cannot be properly tested?

Regards

Comment: I'll tell that to my peers and if they keep asking stuff I'll say im justing quoting Brian d foy. This should work as we learned from your book here :)

Comment: A (good) test is something that provides valuable information to some stakeholder. Completely different question is how you should write unit tests for a perl script. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An important distinction is:  If someone were to edit (bugfix or new feature) your 'script.pl' file, would running your 'script.t' file in its current state give any useful information on the state of the new 'script.pl'?  For this to be the case you must `include` or `use` the .pl file instead of selectively copy/pasting excerpts.

In the best case you design your software modularly and plan for testing.  If you want to test a monolithic script after the fact, I suppose you could write a test script that `include`s your main program after an `exit()` and at least have the subroutines to test...

Answer (score 4):

You can test a program just like a module if you set it up as a modulino. I've written about this all over the place, but most notably in *[Mastering Perl](http://www.masteringperl.org)*. You can [read Chapter 18 for online for free](http://ano-chimera.herokuapp.com/books/1234000001527/ch18.html) right now since I'm working on the second edition in public. :)

Answer (score 2):

Without getting into verification versus validation, etc, a test is any activity that verifies that behavior of something else, that the behaviors match requirements and that certain undesirable behaviors don't occur. The scope of a test can be limited (only verifying a few of the desired behaviors) or it can be comprehensive (verifying most or all of the required or desired behaviors), probably with lots of steps or components to the test to make it so. In my mind, the term "confirmation" in your context is another way of saying "limited scope test". Certainly it doesn't completely verify the behavior of what your testing, but it does something. In direct answer to the question at hand: I think calling what you did a "confirmation" is just a matter of semantics.